# Browser for Android that can save at once all open tabs to bookmarks

Tags: android, web-browser, bookmark

**I need a browser app for Android with the option to save all open tabs to a bookmark folder without making use of a different device**

It seems that all major browsers available on Android don't provide a way to **bookmark all open tabs** at once.

The suggested method to achieve this result usually involves using a sync option and a **desktop app**.

While extensions should usually provide for unimplemented browser features, at this time **it seems extensions aren't available** for most mobile browsers.
(The Yandex browser CAN make use of a very restricted selection of extensions, none of which are relevant).

**REQUIREMENTS**

- it should be available on the official Play Store
- it should be a browser app which allows navigation with multiple tabs
- it should provide the option to save at once all currently open tabs as bookmarks
- *(bookmarks are intended as a list of web pages' titles and addresses that can be selected by the browser as navigation targets)*

Comment: How about firefox + some add-on for the task?

Comment: afaik, Firefox for mobile doesn't support extensions

Comment: Yes, it supports, only it is not very well advertised in the menus. :-)

Comment: You're correct, addons are available. But I haven't found any that work for what I want.

Comment: Hopefully you will get an useful answer.

Comment: I rapidly checked the mozilla website and they still haven't implemented the bookmark api for firefox on android. I guess it's a waiting game, thanks for your help

Comment: They have something called "pocket" or what. It saves all your browsing data into their cloud and shares it between your firefox instances. I don't use it because I do not want to share anything to big black USA buildings, but others yes.